# MySQL convert string to datetime

Tags: php, mysql

In my order table, i have a "delivery_date" field with varchar type and all values ​​look like this :
"d/m/y at H:m"

How can i convert this field and values to a valid datetime Y-m-d H:i:s ?

Comment: You should have to give datatype for your field to datetime.
And before that you can convert your all existing dates to valid date format "Y-m-d H:i:s"

Comment: Ok and how can i handle conversion with STR_TO_DATE ?

Comment: DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(delivery_date, '%d/%m/%y HH:MM'), '%Y-%m-%d HH:MM:SS')

Answer (score 3):

Update your existing dates by following query.

```
update table_name set delivery_date = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(delivery_date, '%d/%m/%y HH:MM'), '%Y-%m-%d HH:MM:SS');
```

After your all dates has been modified by above query, you can change data type to datetime for delivery_date. And make change in your code accordingly for insering new records, updating existing records and related functionality as such we are changing date format.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(delivery_date, '%d/%m/%Y at %H:%i') as date_value
FROM order_table
```

See the [format here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 1):

Since you dont have seconds in your column you will get `00` as second always.

```
SELECT 
 DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(delivery_date, '%d/%m/%y at %H:%i'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as dt 
FROM your_table;
```

**Note:**

But I would suggest convert all your string values to valid `timestamp` by an update query. And later change the data type to `timestamp`.

**These are the steps to be followed:**

```
UPDATE your_table  SET delivery_date =
  DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(delivery_date, '%d/%m/%y at %H:%i'),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

`ALTER TABLE your_table MODIFY delivery_date timestamp;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL's `STR_TO_DATE` function or you could use PHP's `strtotime` funciton.

```
strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Answer (score 0):

use this build-in method from MySQL

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%d %m %Y') AS your_date;
--
DATE_FORMAT('2022-06-12', '%d %m %Y') AS your_date;
```